# What to do for memory related exception while working with NLP Stanford?

Tags: java, maven, stanford-nlp

I am trying to run the Class : Word2VecSentimentRNN from the following link:

https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-examples/blob/master/dl4j-examples/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/examples/recurrent/word2vecsentiment/Word2VecSentimentRNN.java

The example is big one, hence given link of the example here.
Also I have downloaded the Sample vector file from the following link:
https://github.com/mmihaltz/word2vec-GoogleNews-vectors
I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Cannot allocate 3103474 + 3600000000 bytes (> Pointer.maxBytes)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Pointer.deallocator(Pointer.java:484)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Pointer.init(Pointer.java:118)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.FloatPointer.allocateArray(Native Method)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.FloatPointer.<init>(FloatPointer.java:68)
    at org.nd4j.linalg.api.buffer.BaseDataBuffer.<init>(BaseDataBuffer.java:457)
    at org.nd4j.linalg.api.buffer.FloatBuffer.<init>(FloatBuffer.java:57)
    at org.nd4j.linalg.api.buffer.factory.DefaultDataBufferFactory.createFloat(DefaultDataBufferFactory.java:238)
    at org.nd4j.linalg.factory.Nd4j.createBuffer(Nd4j.java:1201)
    at org.nd4j.linalg.factory.Nd4j.createBuffer(Nd4j.java:1176)
    at org.nd4j.linalg.api.ndarray.BaseNDArray.<init>(BaseNDArray.java:230)
    at org.nd4j.linalg.cpu.nativecpu.NDArray.<init>(NDArray.java:111)
    at org.nd4j.linalg.cpu.nativecpu.CpuNDArrayFactory.create(CpuNDArrayFactory.java:247)
    at org.nd4j.linalg.factory.Nd4j.create(Nd4j.java:4261)
    at org.nd4j.linalg.factory.Nd4j.create(Nd4j.java:4227)
    at org.nd4j.linalg.factory.Nd4j.create(Nd4j.java:3501)
    at org.deeplearning4j.models.embeddings.loader.WordVectorSerializer.readBinaryModel(WordVectorSerializer.java:219)
    at org.deeplearning4j.models.embeddings.loader.WordVectorSerializer.loadGoogleModel(WordVectorSerializer.java:118)
    at com.nyu.sentimentanalysis.core.Word2VecSentimentRNN.run(Word2VecSentimentRNN.java:77)
```

I have tried to launch the application with the parameters `-Xmx2g and -Xms2g`. Even changed the values from time to time to check if it helps or work.
Kindly let me know what should I do. Getting locked up here.

Comment: I don't know if this will help, but note that 3600000000 bytes is 3.6 GB, so you might want to run -Xmx4g and see what happens, -Xmx2g is only going to allocated 2 GB

Comment: @StanfordNLPHelp I tried to make it 4G  but it didn't worked. So I changed my PC and shifted to 8GB PC. Now it is running. But while training data now it is showing NullPointer error. That I will figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem running standard Word2vec code and system dies after a while with OutOfMemory.

Following settings worked for me for sustaining long term load on production for DL4J/ND4J based app using Word2vec pre-trained model

*java -Xmx2G -Dorg.bytedeco.javacpp.maxbytes=6G -Dorg.bytedeco.javacpp.maxphysicalbytes=6G*